# Remove all children of an element besides a certain child (or certain children)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that includes many children. I want to remove all children besides 1 or more with a certain class, from that element.

I need a way to remove all children **besides** those I'll keep **selectively**, by their class (or length) and not just by being first or last.

This didn't help:

```
let rightCol = document.querySelector("#rightCol");
let toSave = rightCol.querySelectorAll('._4-u2._3-96._4-u8');
let toSaveArr = [];

toSave.forEach(()=>{
    toSaveArr.push(toSave);
});

rightCol.innerHTML = '';
rightCol.appendChild(toSaveArr);
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the business logic is for which elements stay and which go.

Comment: Not sure I understand the comment... You mean, why I want to take them down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used in the end. Double tested and works. Added comments to explain what is done exactly.

```
// Delete all children besides exceptions (first instance of exception - FIOE):

    let rightCol = document.querySelector("#rightCol");
    let sC1 = document.querySelector('#mySelector1'); // FIOE number 1.
    let savedArr = [];
    savedArr.push(sC1); // Push saved FIOEs to the savedArr to actually save them.
    rightCol.innerHTML = ''; // Delete all data.

for (var i = 0; i < savedArr.length; i++) {
    rightCol.appendChild(savedArr[i]);
}; // Retrieve data from the array.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the elements by looping through them and removing the ones you don't want.

> Note: querySelectorAll().forEach() doesn't work on all browsers. So just use a for on the result of querySelectorAll()

The following will remove all elements that contain the class `a`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#my_div > p.a').forEach(el => {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
})
```

```html
<div id="my_div">
  <p class="a">A</p>
  <p class="b">B</p>
  <p class="a">A</p>
  <p class="a">A</p>
  <p class="B">B</p>
  <p class="B">B</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.querySelector().childNodes to get the list of child nodes and loop through that array.

In each loop check the property and selectivly skip the elements you don't want to remove.

[childNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp)

I am not sure what the conditions are so I leave that to you. This is how I would do it:

Perhaps looping forward doesn't alter the indexes but I am not sure about that, so looping backwards would avoid that problem.

```
var children = document.querySelector("#rightCol").childNodes;
for(var i=children.length - 1; i>= 0; i--){
    if( condition with children[i] is met){
        document.querySelector("#rightCol").removeChild(children[i]);
    }else if( condition with i index is met ){
        document.querySelector("#rightCol").removeChild(children[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will you skip these?

Comment: Added a loop to check the condition on each child or index and evaluate if to remove or not.

Answer (score 0):

> But I need a way to remove all children besides those I'll keep
>   selectively, by their length (1,2,3) or index (0,1,2) and not just by
>   being first or last.

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` and pass `-n+3` to [`:nth-child(][1])` psuedo class selector

```js
let nodes = document.querySelector("div")
            .querySelectorAll("div :nth-child(-n+3)");

nodes.forEach(node => node.parentNode.removeChild(node));
```

```html
<div>
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `-n+3` if `<span>3</span>` still appear? Thanks.

Comment: @OsiOs Have you read the linked MDN document? _"`:nth-child(-n+3)` Represents the first three elements among a group of siblings."_. The first three `<span>` elements are selected and removed from the parent node. Why would you expect `<span>3</span>` to be removed if the requirement is to remove the first three child nodes of the parent node?

Comment: I didn't see any link to MDN so didn't read. I didn't know it takes the **first** three down, but now it makes sense, of course `<span>3</span>` should stay. Thanks.